# Correct way to work with strings that contain "special symbols"?

Tags: javascript, string, special-characters

How can I work with strings which contains pairs of symbols usually used as special. I know about screening '\'. But what if I get a value from an input value? Why there are different rules for parsing values?

```
  el1:<input id="el1" value="C:\files\Input Dir\fileName.txt">
  <br />
  el2:<input id="el2" value="">
   <br />
  el3:<input id="el3" value="">
```

Here we can find the difference

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('el1');
var el2 = document.getElementById('el2');
var el3 = document.getElementById('el3');

var val1 = el1.value;
var val2 = "C:\files\Input Dir\fileName.txt";

console.log(val1);
console.log(val2);
console.log(val1 == val2);

el2.value = val1;
el3.value = val2;
```

You can check this case  at http://jsbin.com/lucurowo/1/edit

Why when I get value from 'штезге', is there no screening for \f , and '\f' understands as string not as form feed marker?

Answer (score 0):

It is not what you get from el1.  This is correct.  It's what you're comparing to (val2) which is incorrect.  You need to escape the escape character which is \.

So your code should be:

```
var val2 = "C:\\files\\Input Dir\\fileName.txt";
```

Comment: If you are generating the HTML through some kind of server-side language `Node.js`, `PHP` or something similar -- it will have a library which will properly escape the HTML. Not just these charters, but many others as well.

Comment: I know about it. Question is about getting code from input - what is the difference ? ( Did you see example at jsbin ? )

Comment: I did see the example at jsbin.  And if you fix the val2 line the problem goes away

Comment: trouble not in the difference between values. I can explain it. I didn't understand why i get value from input with not escaped special symbols - to get correct form

Comment: In your last line you have put the unescaped string into the element:  el3.value = val2;  This is why it is failing to yield what you expect

Comment: i understand. But when i get value from first element - it's looks the same as text value. Why?

Comment: But, it doesn't.  The line `console.log(val1 == val2);` outputs false to the console...

Comment: It may look to you the same.  But when you are viewing the string it just gets displayed as is (with no escaping).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57489/discussion-between-jack-allan-and-vasil-vanchuk).